# How to add a outside layout to vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I wanted to change my vue route from /dashboards/dashboard to just /dashboard.  How to achieve these using this code

```
import Layout2 from '@/layout/Layout2'

export default [
{
    path: '/dashboards',
    component: Layout2,
    children: [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        name: 'dashboard',
        component: () => import('@/components/dashboards/Dashboard')
    }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried putting these code but how can I add the layout2 if the component is already added?

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/dashboard',
    name: 'dashboard',
    component: () => import('@/components/dashboards/Dashboard')
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If [vue-router document](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html)

> Note that nested paths that start with / will be treated as a root
>   path. This allows you to leverage the component nesting without having
>   to use a nested URL.

You can do

```
import Layout2 from '@/layout/Layout2'

export default [
{
    path: '/',
    component: Layout2,
    children: [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        name: 'dashboard',
        component: () => import('@/components/dashboards/Dashboard')
    }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and putting the docs links and explanation.  Really appreciate.